# Any difference between modelobject$residuals and residuals(modelobject) in R package pscl?

Tags: r, models, pscl

I'm trying to build some models using Zero-Inflated Poisson regression using `pscl` package and after having manipulated the output object which turns to be `zeroinfl`, I find that doing `residuals(fm_zip)` is not equal to `fm_zip$residuals`.

The following is an example of what I'm talking about:

```
library("pscl")
data("bioChemists", package = "pscl")
fm_zip <- zeroinfl(art ~ . | 1, data = bioChemists)
names(fm_zip)
fm_zip$residuals
residuals(fm_zip)
all.equal(fm_zip$residuals,residuals(fm_zip))
qplot(fm_zip$residuals,residuals(fm_zip))
```

As you might realize, the results are not equal. I would say that both ways are equivalent but it seems like they're not. Could you explain me what is wrong with this? According to residuals R help, those two alternatives are supposed to return the difference `(observed - fitted)`. By contrast, I did the same with a plain vanilla linear regression and they are equal.

My R version is:

```
sessionInfo()
R version 3.0.1 (2013-05-16)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)...
```

and the package verion is `pscl_1.04.4`

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get equal result you should set `type` to `response` ( pearson by default)

```
 all.equal(fm_zip$residuals,residuals(fm_zip,'response'))
[1] TRUE
```

From the `?residuals.zeroinfl`:

> The residuals method can compute raw residuals (observed - fitted) and
>   Pearson residuals (raw residuals scaled by square root of variance
>   function).

The `perason` variance is defined as:

```
mu <- predict(fm_zip, type = "count")
phi <- predict(fm_zip, type = "zero")
theta1 <- switch(fm_zip$dist, poisson   = 0, 
                              geometric = 1, 
                              negbin    = 1/object$theta)
variance <- fm_zip$fitted.values * (1 + (phi + theta1) * mu)
```

**EDIT**
Don't hesitate to read the code behind, it is generally a source of learning and you can also avoid many confusions. To get the code behind the `S3 method` `residuals.zeroinfl`, you can use something like this :

```
getS3method('residuals','zeroinfl')
```

Comment: Thanks @agstudy. Are those `residuals(fm_zip)` standardized residuals? or what do they stand for?

Comment: @Nestorghh I edit my answer for more details. Hope is is clear now.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer @agstudy. It's been helpful.